# Rewrite rule behaving differently between environments

Tags: .htaccess, lamp

I have two environments, both using Bitnami installations (if that makes a difference). My local environment is WAMP and works correctly. The second is on EC2 using LAMP and does not work correctly. I've done some basic checking and things seem to be setup the same but still give different results.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

The .htaccess page is the same, as are the folder configurations. I have all files in the root folder.

```
-root
  -index.php
  -study.php
```

If I go to //localhost/study/ it correctly redirects to index.php. However on my EC2 instance, it instead goes to study.php. Even if I go to //ec2/study/random/2021/bleh/ it will redirect to study.php. Going to //ec2/random/ will however go correctly to index.php since I do not have a "random" folder.

I've run out of ideas of where to look for configurations differences (I even set "AllowOverride All" in the httpd.conf file and tried -MultiViews). Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you restart the server after disabling **multiviews** on httpd.conf?

Comment: Yup, full reboot of the machine